# mouse hover div kill design for me

Tags: html, css

This my code, I having problem with my css. I have added photo to describe my issue , i hope that make issue clear.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <div class="col-item" >
                <div class="post-img-content">

                    <img src="<?php echo $post['p_image']; ?>" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="img-responsive" />

                    <span class="post-title">
                        <b class="pull-left"><?php echo $post['p_title']?></b>

                     </span>


                </div>
                <div>

                <div class="info" >

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
                        <div class="price col-md-6">

                           <h5><b><?php echo $post['p_category']?></b></h5>

                        </div>
                        <div class=" hidden-sm col-md-6">
                            <h5 style="text-align: right;"><a href="admin-cp/profile.php?user=<?php echo $post['u_id']; ?>"><b ><?php echo $post['u_name']?></b></a></h5>

                        </div>
                        <div class=" hidden-sm col-md-12">
                        <h5><b>Date : </b><?php echo $post['p_date']?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                        <p style="text-align: left;">
                            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i><a href="p_details.php?id=<?php echo $post['p_id']?>" class="hidden-sm">View</a></p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this is css i m using for above code

```
.col-item
    {
        border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #FFF;
    }
    .col-item:hover
    { 
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px -1px #000;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px -1px #000;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px -1px #000;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
      -moz-border-radius: 0px;
      border-radius: 10px;   
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;   
      border-bottom:2px solid #52A1D5;        
    }
    .col-item .photo img
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1px;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0 ;
    }

    .col-item .info
    {
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
        margin-top: 1px;
    }

    .col-item .price
    {
        /*width: 50%;*/
        float: left;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    .col-item .price h5
    {
        line-height: 20px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .price-text-color
    {
        color: #219FD1;
    }





    .col-item .separator
    {
        border-top: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
    }

    .clear-left
    {
        clear: left;
    }

    .col-item .separator p
    {
        line-height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .col-item .separator p i
    {
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    .col-item .btn-add
    {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }

    .col-item .btn-add
    {
        border-right: 1px solid #E1E1E1;

    }

    .col-item .btn-details
    {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
    .controls
    {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    [data-slide="prev"]
    {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    /*
    Hover the image
    */
    .post-img-content
    {
        height: 196px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .post-img-content img
    {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 1px;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0 ;
    }
    .post-title{
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        z-index: 2;
        position: relative;
    }
    .post-title b{
        background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.58);
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-left: 2px;
        color: #FFF;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .post-title b:first-child{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .round-tag{
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
        border: 4px solid #FFF;
        background: #37A12B;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
           padding: 15px 6px;
           font-size: 17px;
            color: #FFF;
            font-weight: bold;}
```

`[this img when i put the mouse over div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlkcA.jpg)

i need help for this issue and i hope you guys help me.

Comment: looks like the :hover styles change the dimensions of the elements, which pushes the following element down. could you provide us with a link to the page?

Comment: Still, the issue is not understandable. Could you please describe the problem?

Comment: it's not page it's on my localhost 
and when i put mouse over first element it push first element in the second row , when i put mouse over 2nd element it push two elements in second row but and 3rd same but , last element didn't do the same 
i don't know why !?
what that issue look like guys ?

Comment: Is it difficult issue to solve?